# Remove elements with the same class

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically built tabs. When you add a tab you give it a class (which is equal to the name you give to the tab), the same class is added to the tab's description, which appears beneath the default description field.

The problem is when I remove a tab I search through `<li>` elements and check whether they have a certain class, if they have, so they get removed. But naturally only tab itself gets removed, but not its description although the description also has the same class like the tab.
Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3ttzqua/).

My code which answerable for removing tabs and description is on lines 59-66 in the JavaScript section (pasted beneath).

```
         /*********Remove a tab******/
        $( ".close" ).click( function(){

            $( this ).closest( "li" ).fadeOut( 200, function() {$( this ).remove();});
            $thisClass = $ ( this ).closest( "li" ).attr( "class" );
            alert ( $thisClass );
            $( "li" ).hasClass( $thisClass ).remove();

        });
```

Comment: `hasClass()` returns a boolean.  It tells you whether an element has a class or not.  You probably want to use `.filter('.'+$thisClass)`.

Comment: Also, `.attr( "class" )` may return you multiple classes (space-separated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same situation as described in fiddle, then

1. you need to remove class 'item' from li classes list
2. correct mistake with hasClass

and you'll get something like this

```
        $( ".close" ).click( function(){

            $( this ).closest( "li" ).fadeOut( 200, function() {$( this ).remove();});
            $thisClass = $ ( this ).closest( "li" ).attr( "class" ).replace('item ','');
            alert ( $thisClass );
            $( "li."+$thisClass ).remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try change `$( "li" ).hasClass( $thisClass ).remove();` to `$('.'+$thisClass).remove();`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$('.'+$thisClass)` or even `$('li.'+$thisClass)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$thisClass = $ ( this ).closest( "li" ).attr( "class" );
```

This will return you *all* the classes on the element.  That element may have more than one class.  If it does, then you'll get a space-separated list of them.

Also `hasClass()` returns a boolean.  It tells you whether an element has a class or not.

You want to do this:

```
$( 'li.'+$thisClass.replace(' ', '.') ).remove();
```